# Reference struct pointer inside struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nested

Apologies for this being so similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856666/access-a-pointer-of-a-structure-inside-another-structure) but I'm having one of those brain-fart moments and am looking for the *Good And Right* way to do this.

I am launching a new pthread to handle some data, which means we can only pass a pointer, in this case because we want to pass several things to the thread the pointer is to a struct.

That data struct itself contains a pointer to another data structure.

So, given this setup, what is the correct way to populate & access the nested struct?

```
struct things_struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct thread_params
{
    int flag;
    struct things_struct *things;
}

int main()
{
    struct thread_params params;
    struct things_struct the_things;

    params.things = &the_things;

    // Launch thread
    pthread_create(&thrptr, NULL, PrintThings, (void *)params);

    //...

}

// The thread
void *PrintThings(void *arg)
{
    struct thread_params *params = (thread_params *)arg; // cast back to correct type

    int local_a = params->things->a; // is this correct?

    //...

}
```

To add a reference to another similar question (I always find them *after* posting) there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373188/c99-pointer-to-a-struct-which-contains-a-pointer-to-a-struct?rq=1) with a similarly simple answer.

Comment: Yes. <!-- do html comments show? -->

Comment: @RedX - Yes they do. Were you actually answering my question or just testing your theory about comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - your way to access member "a" in things_struct is correct.

But - out of my head - you should pass the address of param to phtread_create(...).

```
pthread_create(&thrptr, NULL, PrintThings, (void *)&params);
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't write the rest very thoroughly as it was only for illustration.